# Cordova/Phonegap iOS: no access rights for Facebook Connect plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, plugins, connect

I'm trying to set up Facebook login for my app using this plugin:
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/platforms/ios

I follow the steps and get error messages every time.
Here's a ss of the whole process:
http://xu.cooljon.com/pic/terminal.png

What am I doing wrong to get these errors and what can I do to fix them?

I want to build profiles off of the Facebook authoization.

Comment: what error message you got my friend?

Comment: it's in the screenshot I attached (by link)
http://xu.cooljon.com/pic/terminal.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try install like this one.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" --variable APP_NAME=“cordovasocial”
```

Comment: I had to install with sudo. that seemed to do it.